# Can i insert date in mySQL in "DD-Mon-YY" format"?

Tags: mysql

Mysql support this format YYYY-MM-DD by default.
But what if i want to insert date in this format "dd-Mon-yyyy" in mysql??
Is there any way so that i can insert the manual date in this format.Anyone having any idea??

If possible please write down the insert statement.

Comment: Shortcut : `NOt Possible`

Comment: You can use the [Date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to convert that value – in both directions, when inserting and when reading it out again.

Comment: CBore could you write down the insert statement for inserting a date "14-Apr-85".
Say for an example i have c_info table and i want to enter this date for column dot.

Comment: Why do you need this? Even if you use one of the answers you got, the date will still be converted to "1985-04-14" for internal storage and `SELECT` will return it in this format. If you just want to format the date differently, use the date formatting functions when you `SELECT` the data, not when you insert it.

Comment: @DCoder.yes i can always format the date while displaying on webpage.

Answer (score 4):

Yes using MySql [STRING_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

```
insert into your_table(date_column) values(STR_TO_DATE("09-Sep-2014","%d-%b-%Y"));
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c741f/2)

Answer (score 1):

Try This Format:-

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d-%b-%Y')
```

This will result as:-

`10-Sep-2014`

Hope this will helpful to you.